# Docker - Prometheus container dies immediately

Tags: docker, containers, prometheus, cadvisor

I have cadvisor running with port mapping 4000:8080 and I have to link it with a container with prometheus.

My prometheus.yml is:

```
scrape_configs:
# Scrape Prometheus itself every 2 seconds.
- job_name: 'prometheus'
  scrape_interval: 2s
  target_groups:
  - targets: ['localhost:9090', 'cadvisor:8080']
```

This file has path /home/test/prometheus.yml.
To run the container with prometheus, I do:

```
docker run -d -p 42047:9090  --name=prometheus -v /home/test/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml  --link cadvisor:cadvisor prom/prometheus -config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -storage.local.path=/prometheus -storage.local.memory-chunks=10000
```

The container is created, but it dies immediately. 
Can you tell me where the problem is?

Messages form `docker events&` :

```
2016-11-21T11:43:04.922819454+01:00 container start 69d03c68525c5955cc40757dc973073403b13fdd41c7533f43b7238191088a25 (image=prom/prometheus, name=prometheus)
2016-11-21T11:43:05.152141981+01:00 container die 69d03c68525c5955cc40757dc973073403b13fdd41c7533f43b7238191088a25 (exitCode=1, image=prom/prometheus, name=prometheus)
```

Answer (score 9):

Config format is changed. targets come under static_config in the latest version.

```
scrape_configs:
# Scrape Prometheus itself every 2 seconds.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
  scrape_interval: 2s
  static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090', 'cadvisor:8080']
```

[Prometheus Documentation for further help](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/getting_started/#configuring-prometheus-to-monitor-the-sample-targets)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `target_groups` is renamed to `static_configs`. Please use the latest Prometheus image with the following.

```
static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:9090', 'cadvisor:8080']
```

The above worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I think `target_groups` have been deprecated from `scrape_configs` in latest version of prometheus.
you can try static_configs or file_sd_config

[scrape_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/#scrape_config) 
[static_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/#static_config) 
[file_sd_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/#file_sd_config)

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: node_exporter
    static_configs:
      - targets:
         - "stg-elk-app-01:9100"
         - "stg-app-02:9100"
```

Answer (score 1):

The indentation isn't correct, try:

```
scrape_configs:
  # Scrape Prometheus itself every 2 seconds.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 2s
    target_groups:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090', 'cadvisor:8080']
```

Comment: Which version of Prometheus are you using? `target_groups` was renamed to `static_configs` a while back. This is very difficult to debug without any error output.

Comment: I have done "docker pull prom/prometheus" , so I think it should be the latest (the TAG of the image is ''latest'')

Comment: from logs: time="2016-11-21T11:21:40Z" level=error msg="Error loading config: couldn't load configuration (-config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml): unknown fields in scrape_config: target_groups" source="main.go:149"

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your earlier comment:

`from logs: time="2016-11-21T11:21:40Z" level=error msg="Error loading config: couldn't load configuration (-config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml): unknown fields in scrape_config: target_groups" source="main.go:149"`

Which clearly means that the field "target_groups" is causing the problem. This is due to the fact that the new version of Prometheus (v1.5 onwards) have discarded the use of "target_groups" field and simply provide the targets. Even I faced this issue about 6 months ago. Please try it with a new version. The `docker pull prom/prometheus` might be getting you the old one.

Hope this helps...!!!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the container is `prometheus`.

Generally, when a container exists immediately after it starts, I would recommend adding the `-log.level=debug` right after `-config.file`.

`docker run -d -p 42047:9090  --name=prometheus -v /home/test/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml  --link cadvisor:cadvisor prom/prometheus -config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -log.level=debug -storage.local.path=/prometheus -storage.local.memory-chunks=10000`

Next, see the logs for the container:

`docker logs prometheus`

Any issues with the configuration will be there.